# Test the level of a list for automatic indentation control

Tags: enumitem

I would like to remove the indentation of lists at the first level only to get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
\begin{document}
\noindent text
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0cm]
\item level 1
\begin{itemize}
\item level 2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
text
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to achieve the above result without manually enforcing the option `[leftmargin=0cm]` at the first level. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the \setlist command to set it globally

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=0cm,nosep}
\begin{document}
\noindent text
\begin{itemize}
\item level 1
\begin{itemize}
\item level 2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, can you put an explanation of your code and if is it corresponds to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Ah yes, great, thanks! I completely missed that solution. I was about to have a look at how lists are defined in core Latex...

Comment: @Sebastiano It has been added in the original text.